# How to select textboxes that have a length > 0 with jquery?

Tags: jquery

How would I write a selector that would look through say a div of textboxes and find which ones have a value in the textbox(so length would be greater than zero).

Can I do this all in one selector or do I have to get all textboxes then loop through them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('textarea[value!=""]')
```

Of course, if it's an `input`, you can just modify it:

```
$('input:text[value!=""]')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input:text").filter(function() { return $(this).val().length > 0; })
```

The filter function allows you to provide a custom function which will be called with each currently selected element as `this`, and only the elements for which it returns `true` will stay in the set.

Answer (score 1):

Following should work:

```
nonempty_inputs = $(':input:not(:empty)');
```

If it's only textareas you are interested in, just change `:input` to `textarea`

See also:

- http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
  if ($(this)).val().length > 0)
  {
     alert('I have value !!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[value!=""]')
```